# Sockets python на не локальном хосте

Tags: python, сокет

Нужна помощь при подключении сервера и клиента не на локальном хосте. Я перепробовал много способов сделать это и искал информацию по этой теме, но нигде не смог ее найти. Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Сервер:

```
import socket

serv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0)
serv_sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8090))
serv_sock.listen(10)

while True:
    client_sock, client_addr = serv_sock.accept()
    print('Connected by', client_addr)

    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        client_sock.sendall(data)

    client_sock.close()
```

Клиент:

```
import socket

client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect(('193.109.**.**', 8090)) 
client_sock.sendall(b'Hello, world')
data = client_sock.recv(1024)
client_sock.close()
print('Received', repr(data))
```

Comment: `serv_sock.bind(('', 8090))`

Comment: Не работает(. Выдаёт такую ошыбку: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

Comment: А на сервере порт 8090 открыт?

Comment: По идее да. Я писал комманду netstat -a, и оно на против этого порта писало LISTENING(именно тогда, когда я его запускал).

Comment: У меня кстати по информации из 2ip, все порта почему то закрыты, какой бы я туда порт не вводил, все закрыты. Брандмауер отключен.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669040/i-get-timeouterror-winerror-10060-when-i-parsing-my-school-website

Comment: Я всё прочитал, и не понял что я должен от туда узнать о моей ошибке( Увеличение времени ожидания скорее всего ничего не поменяет. Или же мне нужно использовать не сокеты, а urlib or requests?

Comment: Продолжая рыться в интернете, я нашел вот такой ответ: "Чтобы открыть сокет "listening", чтобы интернет-машины могли связаться с вашей частной машиной, вам нужно перенаправить публичный порт на локальную машину. Например, публичный 1.2.3.4 порт 2222 будет перенаправлен на частный 192.168.1.42 порт 22, так что вы можете ssh ваша машина отовсюду". Но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать...

Answer (score 0):

Информация в вашем последнем комментарии является верной. Вам необходимо откыть и перенаправить порт 8090 (или любой другой) на роутере, с которым вы подключены к интернету, на машину, где у вас запущен сервер.

Наберите в поисковике: <модель роутера> port forwarding, и следуйте инструкциям.
Для распостранённых моделей нверняка будет доступна инструкция на русском.